# Summation of dynamic Text box values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I get the result of SUM(PTsEarned+PtsWithdrawn) in SSRS?
I am trying to use the `=Sum( ReportItems!PtsEarned.Value + ReportItems!PtsWithdrawn.Value)` But I am getting error.
The values for Txtbx PtsEarned and PtsWithdrawn are always changing. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should not include *SUM* in your query.

It should be

*`=( ReportItems!PtsEarned.Value + ReportItems!PtsWithdrawn.Value)`*

You are already using the Add sign to your query.

This will give you a desired result.

Regards
Safi

Comment: Yes,my bad , I forget... It should not contain the aggregate SUM if we just want to add the values of the text boxes.